# running r from linux error: cannot open the connection

Tags: linux, r

I have a R file that was created in windows. The file has below code

```
print(5+7)
fileConn<-file("ch7.txt","w+")
close(fileConn)
```

The code works fine in windows R. But I get an error when i try to run that file from Linux. I have R running on my Linux machine and I typed below command.

```
> source('R_linux.R')
[1] 12
Error in file("ch7.txt", "w+") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file("ch7.txt", "w+") : cannot open file 'ch7.txt': Permission denied
```

Comment: Permission denied could mean it couldn't write to the directory because you don't have proper permissions or that the file already exists but you don't have permission to overwrite it. I guess my first question is. Does a file by that name(`ch7.txt`) already exist?

Comment: no. the file doesnt exist

Comment: In the directory you are trying to write `ch7.txt` to what happens (at a command line) if you do `echo "test data" >ch7.txt` . Does it give permission denied as well?

Answer (score 0):

File permissions are treated differently in linux than they are in windows. I would check that you have read/write access to the file in your linux env.

If your linux has a GUI right click and adjust the permissions.
If you need to do it in the command line try:

```
chmod 664 ch7.txt
```

This will give you read and write access at the user and group levels and read access at the 'other' levels. If you're not too worried about locking down the file you could do:

```
chmod 777 ch7.txt
```

This will give you read/write/execute permissions at user/group/other levels.

Further to this double check that the path is correct. Your working directory may be slightly different by default from machine to machine.

Comment: You can apply the above chmod command to a directory as well.